# custom authentication for certain urls in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm following along the docs about [creating a custom api key authentication for certain urls](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#only-authenticating-for-certain-urls) but I think there's something missing.

If I just `return;` from the `::createToken()` method a `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException` gets thrown and I'm handling that in my [custom exception controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller). The message in the exception is:

`A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.`

It's still forcing me to create a token. I tried removing the `pattern` section in the config but that didn't do anything. I'd expect, for the config below, that any endpoints matching `^/admin` would optionally be authenticated. Ie. Authentication is not required, but will happen if api key is present.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my `security.yml` file

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory_provider:
            id: app.in_memory_user_repository

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: app.authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Here's my authenticator i'm testing this out with:

```
<?php

class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();

        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername("foobar");

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user,
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $request->headers->get('Authorization');

        if (!$apiKey) {
            return;
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anon.',
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['errors' => ["Authentication Failed."]], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to define a provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after digging through some github issues and trying a few things.

The answer is **not** to return null in the `::createToken()` method like it says in the docs. You should always create a `PreAuthenticatedToken` in the `::createToken()` method and create an `AnonymousToken` in the `::authenticateToken()` when a user cannot be located.

Here's the authenticator that behaves as expected

```
<?php

class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();

        if (null === $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($apiKey)) {
            return new AnonymousToken($providerKey, 'anon.');
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user,
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $request->headers->get('Authorization');

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anon.',
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['errors' => ["Authentication Failed."]], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

My `security.yml` file is the same as above. And now every request will not be blocked by authentication to endpoints that match `^/admin` yet i can still check in the controller if they are authenticated or not.

```
<?php

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $authenticated = $this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        return new JsonResponse(['authenticated' => $authenticated]);
    }
}
```